# Pyqt5 Wait until widget is visible

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

I'm looking for a way to wait until a QWidget is fully shown before calling a function. I have two windows: a parent and a child.

The parent form is a window with a button that calls `openChild` which hides parent, shows child, and then execute child's primary function `busyFunc`:

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Child import Child_Form
import sys

class Parent_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Child = Child_Form(self)

    def setupUi(self, Parent):
        Parent.setObjectName("Parent")
        Parent.resize(400, 300)
        self.nextWindow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Parent)
        self.nextWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 91, 31))
        self.nextWindow.setObjectName("nextWindow")

        self.retranslateUi(Parent)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Parent)

    def retranslateUi(self, Parent):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Parent.setWindowTitle(_translate("Parent", "Parent Window"))
        self.nextWindow.setText(_translate("Parent", "Next Window"))

        self.nextWindow.clicked.connect(self.openChild)

    def openChild(self):
        self.hide()
        self.Child.show()
        self.Child.busyFunc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Parent_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The child form just has a label and a scroll area that has a text edit.

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Child_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, Parent_Form):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = Parent_Form

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 361, 241))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 359, 239))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 361, 241))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Child Window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Status:"))

    def busyFunc(self):
        for i in range(0, 1000000000):
            pass
```

The problem is when `busyFunc` is called (the actual function is an enormous program so I've omitted it for clarity. I'm simulating the problem using a loop).

Parent is hidden, but Child looks like this until `busyFunc` is done.

[image]

How can I make child load completely like this and then execute `busyFunc`?

[image]

Comment: If there is any way I can make my question clearer, please say so!

Comment: see my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to launch the busyFunc function after some time through a timer.

```
def openChild(self):
    self.hide()
    self.Child.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.Child.busyFunc)
```

The problem would be that the interface is blocked while running this function, to solve this would recommend running that task on a thread

```
class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0, 1000000000):
            pass

class Child_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, Parent_Form):
        [...]
    def busyFunc(self):
        self.thread = Thread(self)
        self.thread.start()
```

Obviously as the current code of busyFunc does not interact with the GUI, ie does not update any value of the GUI there would be no problem but if this one has to update some data of the GUI it must do through the signals, not directly:

```
class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    signal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        self.signal.emit("start")
        for i in range(0, 1000000000):
            pass
        self.signal.emit("finish")
        self.signal2.emit([1, 2, 3, 4])

class Child_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, Parent_Form):
        [...]
    def busyFunc(self):
        self.thread = Thread(self)
        self.thread.signal.connect(lambda text: self.textEdit.append(text))
        self.thread.signal2.connect(lambda l: print(l))
        self.thread.start() 

class Parent_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        [...]
    def openChild(self):
        self.hide()
        self.Child.show()
        self.Child.busyFunc()
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth solution! I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I tried your solution and almost solves my problem. Is there any way to emit a list from the thread?

Comment: If you can, I've updated the code showing how to do it

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. A threading solution worked perfectly to load the child window while busyFunc was running. Thanks again!